# Placing every character on a new line

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

```
This is a sentence.
This is another sentence.
```

I need to put a new line after each character, such that only one character appears on every line, e.g.:

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

a

s
e
n
t
e
n
c
e
.
T
h
i
s

i
s

a
n
o
t
h
e
r

s
e
n
t
e
n
c
e
.
```

- The file is in UTF-8 and contains many non-English characters.
- It does not matter if spaces or carriage returns have their own line.

How can I remove every character to a new line?

Comment: Do you want every byte on a separate line or every character?

Comment: LOL I always have the opposite problem, I end up writing loops that print each character on its own line when they're supposed to be in sentences :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using sed replace every character with itself followed by a newline:

```
sed 's/./\0\n/g' -i filename
```

Comment: OS X's equivalent: `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g' -i '' filename`

Comment: Almost the same but a bit easier:
`sed 's/./\0\n/g' -i filename`

Comment: Thanks @ŠťastnýJakub , I like that better so I edited the answer

Answer (score 19):

- `sed $'s/./&\\\n/g'` (with BSD sed)

  - Or `sed 's/./&\n/g'` with GNU sed
  - Doesn't include empty lines for linefeeds
- `fold -w1`

  - `-w` specifies width in characters
  - Doesn't include empty lines for linefeeds
- `while IFS= read -r -n1 -d '' c; do printf %s\\n "$c"; done`

  - Includes empty lines for linefeeds with `-d ''`
  - The only option for `read` specified by POSIX is `-r`
- `gawk -F '' 'OFS="\n"{$1=$1}1'`

  - Or `awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1'` in nawk (BSD awk, the awk that comes with OS X); it doesn't work with multibyte characters though
  - Neither includes empty lines for linefeeds

All except the nawk command worked with non-ASCII characters in my environment when `LC_CTYPE` was set to a UTF-8 locale. None collapsed or stripped spaces.

Answer (score 12):

Use `grep`, in example:

```
$ grep -o . file
$ echo This is a sentence. | grep -o .
```

or `fold`:

```
$ fold -w1 file
$ echo This is a sentence. | fold -w1
```

Answer (score 5):

Using awk's input and output field separators:

```
awk -F '' -v 'OFS=\n' '{$1=$1}1' filename
```

or Perl

```
perl -F// -lane 'print join "\n", @F' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as short as [PaulP.R.O.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899081/96588), but useful if you want to do some operation on each character:

```
while read -r -n 1 -d '' -u 9
do
    printf "Uppercase '${REPLY^^}', "
    printf "lowercase '${REPLY,,}', "
    printf "literal $(printf "$REPLY" | uniname -bcegpu | tail -1)"
    printf '\n'
done 9< "path"
```