# How I can place every three characters on a new line?

Tags: string, shell

I have a file containing strings, in example:

```
ATCGGTCAA
```

I need to put a new line after every three characters, such that only each three characters appear on every line, e.g.:

```
ATC
GGT
CAA
```

How can I make this conversion in shell?

Comment: `'\n'.join(input[x*3:(x+1)*3] for x in xrange(len(input)/3))`

Comment: Use the modulo: if(i%3 == 0) then newline

Comment: If you do so, make sure that you start from the end rather than the beginning; otherwise you'll be changing the length indices of the remaining substring that you have to work with.

Comment: Use grep, in example: `grep -o ...`

Comment: Similar: [Placing every character on a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9899049/55075)

Answer (score 10):

Use the [fold](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!man+fold) shell command:

```
fold -w3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e '$/=\3; while(<>) { print $_ . "\n" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a unix command called `fold`:

```
fold -3 < inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

A python version:

```
chunk = in.read(3)
while len(chunk) > 0:
    out.write(chunk + "\n")
    chunk = in.read(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   print("$_\n") for /.{1,3}/sg;
}
```

Script-less: (aka one-liner aka bash)

```
perl -nle'print for /.{1,3}/sg' file.in >file.out

perl -i~ -nle'print for /.{1,3}/sg' file    # In-place
```

Features:

- You don't end up with blank line at the end.
- It works even if you don't have a newline at the end.
- It works even if you don't have a multiple of three chars.
- It works even if you have multiple lines.

(Update) Note that all the other solutions currently posted (William Pursell, Hunter McMillen and anttix) add a blank line.
(Update) And jterrace's

Comment: No need for `/s` with `-l` / `chomp`

Comment: @Borodin, I could also use `/[^\n]{1,3}/`. But why would I want to.

Comment: You wouldn't, for the same reason you wouldn't want to use an unnecessary `/s`: because readability is paramount.

Comment: @Borodin, Exactly, and `.` without "s" is one of the trickiest atoms from point of view of readability. It works and does what you want most of the time, until the one time it doesn't do what you expect it to do (match a character).  Since `/s` comes at the end, it doesn't add to the mental load. It simply confirms that you understood the pattern correctly, so it doesn't harm readability. Without the `/s`, I have to go back, reparse the pattern to make sure `.` doesn't do something different than expected.

Comment: @Boridin, Therefore, if my pattern uses `.`, it will have a `/s` (unless it's rare time I specifically don't want to match a newline).

Comment: You will have to excuse me if I disagree with you completely. All this would be fine if it was usual to see a superfluous `/s` modifier, but as it is, if a regular expression has a modifier I look for how it modifies the expression. It took me several seconds to be certain that it had no effect in this instance, and I shall have to add it to the eccentricities I have to bear in mind when I scan your code.

Comment: @Borodin, `(?s)` no more "modifies the expression" than `(?-s)`. Considering practically all regular expressions with `.` need `/s` (or don't care), I dare say that the lack of `/s` "modifies the expression" *more* if you think there's one of them is more default than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using the modulus operator on the length of the string.

pseudo-code:

```
myString = "ATCGGTCAA";
count = 0;

for(c in myString)
{  
   if((count+1) % 3 == 0 && count != 0) print "\n";
   print c;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't read from a file.

Comment: Then instead of myString, use open(myfilename).read(), which gives you a String representing all the content in the file "myfilename".

Comment: @ikegami The question doesn't say anything about a file.

Comment: It starts "I have a file like this:"

Comment: hmm I read that as 'I have a line like this'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU sed on Linux

```
sed -i .bak -e 's/.../&\n/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another python one-line:

```
a = 'ATCGGTCAA'
splitted = '\n'.join([a[i:i+3] for i in range(len(a) / 3)])
```

Comment: 1) That doesn't read from a file. 2) "One liner" actually means "easily executable from the shell". Please add the missing bits of your one-liner.

Comment: You could probably save yourself from typing a set of square brackets by changing your list-comp to a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

An overly clever (but fun) python 2-liner:

```
a=iter( 'ATCGGTCAA' )
print '\n'.join( ''.join(x) for x in zip(a,a,a) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
in=f.read() #'ATCGGTCAA...'
out=''
count=0
for i in s:
    out+=i
    count+=1
    if not count%3:
        out+='\n'
print>>f2, out
```

Output:

```
ATC
GGT
CAA
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
,[.,.,.[-]++++++++++.,]
```