# How can I insert a new line after each character in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, newline

Assuming I have the following string:

```
abcdefghi
```

Which command can I use so that the outcome is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

I just started coding so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing every character on a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899049/placing-every-character-on-a-new-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a tool called [`fold`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fold.html) which inserts linebreaks, and you can tell it do add one after every character:

```
$ fold -w 1 <<< 'abcdefghi'
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

`<<<` is used to indicate a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings). If your shell doesn't support that, you can pipe to `fold` instead:

```
echo 'abcdefghi' | fold -w 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`, although it will add an extra newline after the last letter so you get a blank line at the end:

```
$ sed 's/./&\
/g' <<<abcdefghi
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i

$
```

s/*old*/*new*/ is the sed "substitute" command.  On the *old* side, the pattern `.` matches any character at all.  On the *new* side, the symbol `&` means "whatever the *old* pattern matched" - we include what we match in the replacement so we are adding things, not removing them.

We want to follow each matched character with a newline, but the newline will terminate the `sed` command and result in a syntax error unless we put a backslash in front of it.

So we are replacing any character at all (`.`) with that same character (`&`) followed by a newline (`\` + newline).  The `g` on the end means to replace every occurrence, not just the first one on each line.

The demonstration uses a here-string, which is part of most modern shells but not all; you could also do it with `echo abcdefghi | sed '...'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o . <<< "abcdefghi"
```